# "cannot detect OpenGL context" when using Pygame and moderngl?

Tags: python, pygame, python-moderngl

I wrote the simple program below:

```py
import pygame as pg
import moderngl as mgl
import sys

class GraphicsEngine:
    def __init__(self, win_size=(1200,700)):
        pg.init()

        self.WIN_SIZE = win_size
        pg.display.gl_set_attribute(pg.GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3)
        pg.display.gl_set_attribute(pg.GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3)
        pg.display.gl_set_attribute(pg.GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, pg.GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE)

        pg.display.set_mode(self.WIN_SIZE, flags=pg.OPENGL | pg.DOUBLEBUF)

        self.ctx = mgl.create_context()

        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()

    def check_events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT or (event.type == pg.KEYDOWN and event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE):
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()
    
    def render(self):
        self.ctx.clear(color=(0.08, 0.16, 0.18))

        pg.display.flip()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.check_events()
            self.render()
            self.clock.tick(60)
            pg.display.set_caption(pg.time.get_fps())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=GraphicsEngine()
    app.run()
```

and I get this error

```
File "path\main.py", line 41, in <module>
    app=GraphicsEngine()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path\main.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.ctx = mgl.create_context()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site->packages\moderngl\context.py", line 1968, in create_context
    ctx.mglo, ctx.version_code = >mgl.create_context(glversion=require, mode=mode, **settings)
                                 >^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site->packages\glcontext\__init__.py", line 69, in create
    return wgl.create_context(**kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Exception: cannot detect OpenGL context
```

I tried to reinstall moderngl but nothing changed

Comment: The problem is not reproducible.

Comment: Also, you say you "found a tutorial on the internet" – _which_ tutorial? If you're posting code slightly-modified from somewhere, you should link to the source.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 No, that is not what I mean. I have tested the code and it works fine for me. So the problem is in the system and not in the code and thus the question is off-topic

Comment: @wizzwizz4 It's a problem with the system because the code works with my system. (Windows - like the contributor's system).

Comment: @Error Are you getting any `pygame`-related messages before that error?

Comment: @Error What happens if you call `pygame.display.init()` separately?

Answer (score 3):

Let's start at the end of your traceback:

> ```
>   File "C:\Python311\site-packages\glcontext\__init__.py", line 69, in create
>     return wgl.create_context(**kwargs)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> Exception: cannot detect OpenGL context
> ```

Looking in `__init__.py`, we don't find the string `"cannot detect OpenGL context"`. But, on line 56, we *do* find:

```
from glcontext import wgl
```

In `moderngl`'s source code, we find a file `wgl.cpp`, with the lines (119–123):

```cpp
res->hrc = res->m_wglGetCurrentContext();
if (!res->hrc) {
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_Exception, "cannot detect OpenGL context");
    return NULL;
}
```

I don't know what `res->hrc` is, but nor do I need to, because it's the return value of `res->m_wglGetCurrentContext()`, and *that* function comes from line 80:

```cpp
res->m_wglGetCurrentContext = (m_wglGetCurrentContextProc)GetProcAddress(res->libgl, "wglGetCurrentContext");
```

A little earlier (line 73), we see that `res->libgl` is:

```cpp
res->libgl = LoadLibraryEx(libgl, NULL, (DWORD)load_mode);
```

where `libgl` is (line 50):

```cpp
const char * libgl = "opengl32.dll";
```

So there's a problem with the `wglGetCurrentContext` function from `opengl32.dll`. Let's check [Microsoft's Win32API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-wglgetcurrentcontext):

> If the calling thread has a current OpenGL rendering context, `wglGetCurrentContext` returns a handle to that rendering context. Otherwise, the return value is `NULL`.

The `!res->hrc` on line 120 is checking for `NULL`, so this looks like our culprit!

Now, why is there no OpenGL rendering context...?

### Standalone hypothesis

The Windows API documentation tells us how to create an OpenGL context – and, indeed, there's a function `res->m_wglCreateContext` in `wgl.cpp`. It's called on line 214, inside an `if` block starting at line 180:

```cpp
if (!strcmp(mode, "standalone")) {
```

Where does `mode` come from? Lines 49–55:

```cpp
const char * mode = "detect";
const char * libgl = "opengl32.dll";
int glversion = 330;

if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, "|ssi", keywords, &mode, &libgl, &glversion)) {
    return NULL;
}
```

It *looks* hardcoded… but it doesn't look like it's supposed to be. Let's check [the Python documentation for `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/c-api/arg.html#c.PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords):

> Parse the parameters of a function that takes both positional and keyword parameters into local variables. The keywords argument is a `NULL`-terminated array of keyword parameter names. Empty names denote positional-only parameters. Returns true on success; on failure, it returns false and raises the appropriate exception.

Not terribly useful, but [Stack Overflow yields some code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35068114/5223757) and, put together, we can see that `mode` is a bog-standard Python kwarg.

So, following the keyword arguments up the traceback, consulting the source code of each function, we find that changing your line 16:

```
self.ctx = mgl.create_context()
```

to:

```
self.ctx = mgl.create_context(standalone=True)
```

fixes the *immediate* problem: now an OpenGL context is created. However, it doesn't seem to *do* anything.

### Pygame hypothesis

The [ModernGL documentation](https://moderngl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/the_guide/basic.html) says:

> ModernGL can only create headless contexts (no window), but it can also detect and use contexts from a large range of window libraries.

As [Rabbid76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5577765/rabbid76) identified, ModernGL is *supposed* to pick up the context from `pygame`. The fact it doesn't is curious. They *should* be created by `pygame.init()`, so let's track that down.

```
>>> import pygame
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
>>> pygame.init
<built-in function init>
>>> pygame.init.__doc__
'init() -> (numpass, numfail)\ninitialize all imported pygame modules
```

So `pygame.init` is defined in C – as one might expect. `base.c`'s `pg_init` has an identical function and an identical return type, so I'll assume that's it. Lines 341–343:

```c
/* Put all the module names we want to init in this array */
const char *modnames[] = {
    IMPPREFIX "display", /* Display first, this also inits event,time */
    IMPPREFIX "joystick", IMPPREFIX "font", IMPPREFIX "freetype",
    IMPPREFIX "mixer",
    /* IMPPREFIX "_sdl2.controller", Is this required? Comment for now*/
    NULL};
```

Lines 361–368:

```c
if (pg_mod_autoinit(modnames[i]))
    success++;
else {
    /* ImportError is neither counted as success nor failure */
    if (!PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_ImportError))
        fail++;
    PyErr_Clear();
}
```

`pgmod_autoinit` looks for a function named `_internal_mod_init` and, failing that, a function called `init`. The `pygame.display` module handles SDL2, which handles OpenGL contexts; `display._internal_mod_init` doesn't exist, but `pygame.display.init` *does*. The relevant section:

```c
const char *drivername;
/* Compatibility:
 * windib video driver was renamed in SDL2, and we don't want it to fail.
 */
drivername = SDL_getenv("SDL_VIDEODRIVER");
if (drivername &&
    !SDL_strncasecmp("windib", drivername, SDL_strlen(drivername))) {
    SDL_setenv("SDL_VIDEODRIVER", "windows", 1);
}
if (!SDL_WasInit(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)) {
    if (!_pg_mac_display_init())
        return NULL;

    if (SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO))
        return RAISE(pgExc_SDLError, SDL_GetError());
}
```

(`return NULL;` means an exception occurred, and it should be re-raised.)

SDL2's code is pretty solid, so there's *probably* no bug there. However, recall the code from `base.c`: if this code fails, `pygame.init()` will *swallow the exception*, and the only way you'd know anything went wrong is if you checked the return value.

It's probably *possible* to debug this further by looking into SDL2's source code, to find the conditions under which `wglCreateContext` doesn't get called, but the easiest way would be to check `pygame.init()`'s return value.

Comment: @Rabbid76 That'll teach me to be lazy. Fixed.

Comment: `self.ctx = mgl.create_context(standalone=True)` causes my system to hang. `self.ctx = mgl.create_context()` still works fine.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Okay, [the documentation shed some light into this issue](https://moderngl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/the_guide/basic.html). Maybe we should've started with that.

Comment: `ctx = moderngl.create_context()` detects an active context. The context is created by Pygame. Also see https://moderngl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/context.html

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to my problem. it was some problem with environment variables, it was enough to remove one variable that shouldn't be there and reinstall moderngl. thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Which "variable" did you remove?

Comment: I dont remember full name but it's like  OPENGL_CONTEXT_(propably)CREATE

Comment: It was only not windows user variable(all variables I adding for all user)

Comment: @Error, thanks for posting what worked (though it would've been nice to have more details). Future readers, if you've encountered this issue, please record the name of the environment variable! (And re-installing moderngl _probably_ has nothing to do with fixing this issue.)