# PYCFunctionWithKeywords being called incorrectly from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I am trying to write a C-extension module for python3, say `foo` and I am trying to define method that can take keyword arguments.

```
static PyObject* fooImpl(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*);
static PyObject* fooImpl2(PyObject, PyObject*);
static PyMethodDef fooMethods[] = {
    {"foo_impl", (PyCFunction) fooImpl, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "Some description"},
    {"foo_impl2", fooImpl2, METH_VARARGS, "Some description"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyObject* fooImpl(PyObject* self, PyObject* args, PyObject* kwds) {
    static const char *keywordList[] = { "kw1", "kw2", NULL};
    PyObject *input = nullptr;
    PyObject *kw1Val = nullptr;
    PyObject *kw2Val = nullptr;
    PyObject *returnVal = nullptr;
    int err = PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "O|OO",
                                          const_cast<char**>(keywordList),
                                          &input, &kw1Val, &kw2Val);
    if (!err) {
       return NULL;
    }
    //// Do something with args to compute returnVal
    return returnVal;
}
```

When I try this within python, I get the following error

```
>>> import foo as fp
>>> arg1 = ...
>>> arg2 = ...
>>> arg3 = ...
>>> a = fp.foo_impl(arg1, kw1 = arg2, kw2 = arg3);
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Seems like the interpreter is not registering the `METH_KEYWORDS` flag in the `PyMethodDef` . Is there someother way to add `PyCFunctionWithKeywords` methods to C-extension in Python3 . The only source I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264080/python-c-extension-why-are-methods-that-use-keyword-arguments-cast-to-pycfunct) stackoverflow post that goes back to the Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example])

Any help is deeply appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't define all the keywords. Even if the argument is non-optional, it still needs to have a name defined, so it can be passed by keyword or positionally (and so `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords` can match up positions with keywords, in case the optional arguments are passed positionally). Basically, the number of keyword names must always match the maximum number of arguments to parse.

Change:

```
static const char *keywordList[] = { "kw1", "kw2", NULL};
```

to:

```
static const char *keywordList[] = { "input", "kw1", "kw2", NULL};
```

Obviously, you can name the first argument whatever you want; I just matched the C variable name.

Comment: Thanks ShadowRanger. I just figured out the answer myself too by looking at the code in Python.